# How to read extract data between parantheses and print it to another file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I am looking a method to extract a particular text from multiple parentheses and wanted to store in a file. The content looks like this.

```
{& Vendor CGIO} 1100 650} {{& IP_OWNER cjohn} 1100 550} {{& Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2} 1100 450} {{& DATE_TIME Aug 29 03:27:36 2016} 1100 750} {{& Version 1.1} 1100 350} {{& PDK_RELEASE_VERSION V1} 1100 850}
```

I wanted to extract following and print into a file.

```
& Vendor CGIO
& IP_OWNER cjohn
& Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2
& Version 1.1
```

I tried using cut command but its not so useful to extract all variables.

```
cat Tags_file | cut -d '{' -f2 | cut -d '}' -f1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `grep -oP` with lookaround based regex:

```
grep -oP '(?<={)[^{}]+(?=})' file

& Vendor CGIO
& IP_OWNER cjohn
& Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2
& DATE_TIME Aug 29 03:27:36 2016
& Version 1.1
& PDK_RELEASE_VERSION V1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `while` loop will also print the outputs:

```
my $str = '{& Vendor CGIO} 1100 650} {{& IP_OWNER cjohn} 1100 550} {{& Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2} 1100 450} {{& DATE_TIME Aug 29 03:27:36 2016} 1100 750} {{& Version 1.1} 1100 350} {{& PDK_RELEASE_VERSION V1} 1100 850}';

print "$1\n" while($str=~m/\{([^\{\}]*)\}/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep -Poh '(?<={)& (?!DATE|PDK)[^}]+' Tags_file
```

What I got:

```
& Vendor CGIO
& IP_OWNER cjohn
& Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2
& Version 1.1
```

Just what you needed. (excluded `DATE_TIME` and `PDK` as in your example)

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9iAPW/1)

Answer (score 1):

First, change all `{&` to `newlines,` then get rid of the remaining *noise* (note that I removed the initial `&` also):

```
$ echo "{& Vendor CGIO} 1100 650} {{& IP_OWNER cjohn} 1100 550} {{& Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2} 1100 450} {{& DATE_TIME Aug 29 03:27:36 2016} 1100 750} {{& Version 1.1} 1100 350} {{& PDK_RELEASE_VERSION V1} 1100 850}" 
| sed 's/{&/\n/g' | awk -F\} '{ print $1 }'

 Vendor CGIO
 IP_OWNER cjohn
 Product pk_sgmii_serdes_sx_ico_idac_sw_by2
 DATE_TIME Aug 29 03:27:36 2016
 Version 1.1
 PDK_RELEASE_VERSION V1
```